# How to intercept update requests in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, staging

We are currently engaging a staging environment. In the vendor's infinite wisdom, they use composite primary keys for relationships, meaning if I update the relationship I update the key as well breaking the staging service.

Is there a way to intercept update requests for certain mapped classes, turning them into creates instead?

Comment: do you mean turn updates into inserts?

Comment: I mean when I receive an update I want to turn it into a delete of the existing key than insert of the new value. Instead of just an update to the primary key field. This could also be a bad question if I am misunderstanding how Hibernate handles this.

Comment: I believe Hibernate supports composite keys, if that would solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your Hibernate entities to use composite key. Maybe this would help.

If you need to intercept certain operation in Hibernate you can use [callbacks](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html).

If you need more flexibility, think of using [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) ([with Spring it is quite simple](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html)). They allow to intercept anything one can imagine.

Comment: I am curious how composite keys would "solve the issue" Won't they still call an update when the composite key changes? Whenever the key changes I need a delete and insert I will check on your links.

Comment: Relationships using composite keys can also be mapped in hibernate..why do you want to turn an update into insert?